# Synchronize two databases with differing levels of normalization

Tags: mysql, migration, data-migration, database-migration

I have two tables. Table A is brand new and relatively normalized. Table B is old and completely breaks all levels of normalization.

I'm creating a brand new system using table A, but table B is still in heavy use by our entire staff until the new system is up and running at which time we'll make an assessment on whether or not we're ready to flip the switch.

We use a typical LAMP stack PHP/MySQL. My question is this: How can I customize/make a migration from Table B to Table A? Keep in mind I'm not necessarily worried if the data is diff'd and what not. My concern is the overall structure.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is really better off on StackOverflow, but I think the answer you'll get is "Don't DO that! Write your new system, populate it with test data & test it, then write a script to sync everything once and kill the old system in one fell swoop"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could consider using a VIEW so that you can present the data from Table B in the same structure as Table A. Then switchover would be as simple as:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_a LIKE table_a;
INSERT INTO new_table_a SELECT * FROM table_a;
DROP VIEW table_a;
ALTER TABLE new_table_a RENAME table_a;
```